# How to Disable Downloading in Chromium CEF3

Tags: delphi, tchromium

How to Disable Downloading in Chromium CEF3? I looked in the event onBeforeDownload but can't find a thing. All the parameters are constant. If I don't put any code in it will still continue to download. Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't tried it, but what happens if you put an "Abort;" in the OnBeforeDownload event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, all downloads are cancelled :
https://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefDownloadHandler.html

You can also use the TChromium.OnDownloadUpdated event and execute this to cancel the download :

```
callback.cancel;
```